# DocX4: How to add table in word docx using Quick part field and write to that template with a table

Tags: docx4j

I would like to add table in my docx template. I know how to do it with just a simple field and how to use that template and write the value to it. But how can I create a table and write to the template. Assuming I have a list of Students object, how am I going to write it in a table?

This is how you add field name.

> Quick Parts > Fields > Choose MergeField in the category and write the
>   desired field name

And here's how to write the value to it using docx4j

```
Map<DataFieldName, String> map = new HashMap<DataFieldName, String>();
map.put(new DataFieldName("myName"),"yourName");
                MailMerger.setMERGEFIELDInOutput(MailMerger.OutputField.DEFAULT);

MailMerger.performMerge(template, map, true);

template.save(new File("C:/temp/OUT_SIMPLE.docx") );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want one row per list item, the easiest way is to iterate through the list, writing your table rows.

To generate suitable code, create a Word document with the table looking as you want it, then [generate corresponding code](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html).

Alternatively, you could use OpenDoPE content control data binding, wrapping a repeat around a table row. This is a more generic solution, but with a learning curve...

Comment: Hi @JasonPlutext, could you give an example please. I've seen code that writes in a table but none of use mergeField .. 1) http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-complex-word-docx-documents-programatically-docx4j 2) http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-complex-word-docx-documents-programatically-docx4j . Im using MailMerger to write in a template but I think I could not use the same class to write a table.

Comment: You can't do what I understand you to want using MERGEFIELD.  But see http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?p=495954

Comment: my bad, maybe you misinterpret my question. I'll try to rephrase it, I'd like to create a template with table using mergefield, I want to know how to use docx4j to populate the table.... I think that it is possible to populate a table in a template using docx4j because there is a keyword and samples with Merge TableStart and MergeField TableEnd in docx, surely docx4j didn't forget to implement that one, here it is https://www.genus.no/?ArticleKey=IDA444FE8AEDDC4DE8

Comment: Those are Genus proprietary extensions.  They could be replicated in docx4j, but nobody has done that yet.

Comment: if MergeField isn't possible, What options do I have? use DocVariable etc.?  I've seen a code that uses DocVariable in the template, but it seems that table is hardcoded. The screenshot doesn't show a variable being used in the table. Here it is https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/HowTo/3.9/Creating_Word_Reports_with_Docx4j . The template will be created by the user so they can do anything that they want in table like change the position of the columns, show only the field that they would like to see, etc. so as much as possible I dont want the code to be hardcoded. Thanks

Comment: If a user creates the template, sounds like OpenDoPE content control data binding is worth exploring.  This example docx repeats table rows: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/sample-docs/word/databinding/invoice.docx?raw=true